# Design of an LNA housing box for a UHF/VHF satellite ground station

Tags: vhf, uhf, rf-power, amplifier, lna

I'm currently designing a waterproof metallic case to house LNAs, power cables, and RF switches for a UHF/VHF satellite ground station. As shown in the diagram below, the antennas are connected to an absorptive RF switch by a 5-meter RF cable. The switch is controlled by an external 12-volt input from a PLC. To minimize space and resources, I would like to use a single box. However, I read somewhere that the VHF HPA can generate harmonics that could interfere with UHF. Should I use two separate boxes for UHF and VHF or one box should be fine? Feel free to add more suggestions to improve the design.

Thanks in advance.

[image]